# Link color inside Code

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

It's hard to spot a [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com) inside [`code`](http://unix.stackexchange.com) elements.

Maybe `this` is a link, or [`this`](http://unix.stackexchange.com)?

<sub>(There are three links in this question, can you find them? :)</sub>

Comment: i'll fix this soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put in a fix, should be in the next build.